# A problem about nullity of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have trouble with this problem:

If $A$ is a $4 \times 5$ matrix such that $\overrightarrow{v} \mapsto A \overrightarrow{v}$ is surjective, what is $nul A$?

I know that 
\begin{equation}
nul A = dim A - rank A
\end{equation}
In this problem, $dim  A = 4\times 5 = 20$, but I can't figure out $rankA$. How to find out $rankA$ from the given condition?

Comment: With $nul$, do you mean the dimension of the kernel?

Comment: $\dim A$ should be dimension of the domain of $A:\Bbb R^5\to \Bbb R^4$. It is $5$, not $5\times 4$.

Comment: Use Gauss elimination to derive the rank. This is all basic.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Gauss elimination isn't needed here.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Apparently, we do not know $A$, but we know that the corresponding map is surjective. We cannot use Gauss elimination here because $A$ is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the linear map $T_A\in L(F^5,F^4)$ that maps $v\to Av$ is given to be surjective. This implies that
$$\dim({\text{range}\ T_A})=4.$$
Now apply rank nullity theorem.

I hope you know that nullity of $A$ is equal to $\dim{\ker{T_A}}$, in this case.